# How to refresh all materialized views by using select and loop

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have created the following script to get a list of all materialized views and execute refresh for each materialized view.

```
/* Formatted on 21/03/2018 5:00:01 PM (QP5 v5.114.809.3010) */
DECLARE
   NAM   VARCHAR2(252);
BEGIN
   FOR OUTPUT
   IN (SELECT   'dbms_refresh.refresh(''' || name || ''');'
         INTO   NAM
         FROM   all_snapshots)
   LOOP
 EXEC OUTPUT.NAM;
   END LOOP;
END;
```

The select statements generate the SQL statement and then I need to execute the command to refresh each materialized view.

I know that I can use the following code to refresh all the materialized views in one shot but somehow Oracle creates a job but doesn't execute it:

```
DECLARE
v_number_of_failures NUMBER(12) := 0;
BEGIN
DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH_ALL_MVIEWS(v_number_of_failures,'C','', TRUE, FALSE);
END;
```

I am more interested in the script which I made, kindly correct me where I am going wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: Two immediate observations: (1) EXEC is a SQL\*Plus command, PL/SQL does not understand it; (2) You can't loop over a SELECT ... **INTO**, how do you think that would work?

Comment: `dbms_refresh.refresh` makes a refresh of entire **Refresh Group**. In order to refresh single materialized view run `DBMS_CUBE.REFRESH_MVIEW(...)`

Answer (score 2):

The correct script would be

```
/* Formatted on 21/03/2018 5:00:01 PM (QP5 v5.114.809.3010) */
DECLARE
   NAM   VARCHAR2(252);
BEGIN
   FOR OUTPUT
   IN (SELECT   name
       FROM   all_snapshots)
   LOOP
     dbms_refresh.refresh(OUTPUT.name);
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Be aware that the contents of the materialized views would be inconsistent, because they are refreshed on after another. Use a refresh group or set transaction_isolation=serializable to refresh them consistently.

The reason why your job wasn't executed might be you forgot to commit.